# Why qiskit transpiler makes different results everytime? (Non-deterministic)

Tags: programming, qiskit, transpile

I tried to do qubit mapping called 'SABRE' and execute transpiled quantum circuit.
I use FakeTokyo backend which has some noise because it is mock version of IBMQ 20-Tokyo.
I know using this backend makes some noise but will not change final result when I measure my circuit. But, when I transpile my quantum circuit like below code, the result is always different. I wonder why this happens.

Source code:

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeTokyo
from qiskit.circuit.measure import measure
from qiskit.execute_function import execute
from qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

backend = FakeTokyo()

final_circuit = transpile(circuits=circuit,
                          backend=backend,
                          routing_method='sabre',
                          layout_method='sabre',
                          basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx', 'id'])

final_circuit.barrier()
final_circuit.measure_all()

results = execute(final_circuit, backend).result()
counts = results.get_counts()
print("result : ", counts)
```

`circuits = circuit` means I input list of quantum circuits into transpile function. I really don't know why the results always different.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `seed_transpiler`. See the documentation for `transpiler()` [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html).

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeTokyo
from qiskit.circuit.measure import measure
from qiskit.execute_function import execute
from qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

backend = FakeTokyo()

final_circuit = transpile(circuits=circuit,
                          backend=backend,
                          routing_method='sabre',
                          layout_method='sabre',  
                          seed_transpiler= 1000,
                          basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx', 'id'])

final_circuit.barrier()
final_circuit.measure_all()

results = execute(final_circuit, backend).result()
counts = results.get_counts()
print("result : ", counts)
```

Comment: What is seed_transpiler? Please show me the example of seed_transpiler

Comment: It sets random seed for the stochastic parts of the transpiler. The transpiler/compiler uses a heuristic approach at decomposing the circuit. If you set the seed to a specific value then the transpiled circuit will be the same each time. If not, then each execution, the transpiler will pick a random seed hence lead to different results. Look at the code I put down... which is the same as the code you had, I just set the seed to a fixed value of 1000.

Comment: Thank you, I found the seed what I need. But I wonder two things.

Comment: 1. Should I need to set specific seed to get the result that I need?
2. What is seed exactly?

Comment: 1) You can set it to any specific value you want. But keep it the same through out. 2) See this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: Just a quick note: even though the author seems to be satisfied, this does not answer the question *why* but rather shows *how*. I suspect the *why* is because of the layout method that, if I remember well, starts with a random layout and try to improve it using SABRE routing algorithm (the actual procedure is depicted in SABRE paper).